# Links breaking when View Serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following as part of a View Model that populates a partial view:

```
public string DownloadLink
{
    get
    {
        UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        switch (this.Type)
        {
            case (int)DocumentTypes.WasteNote: { 

                return url.Action("PaperWork", "Jobs", new { JobId = this.DOCJobId }, HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https" : "http" ); 
            }
            case (int)DocumentTypes.Contract:
            case (int)DocumentTypes.DestructionCert:
            case (int)DocumentTypes.Quote:
            default: { return url.Action("Download", "Documents", new { DocId = this.DocumentLinkId }, HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https" : "http"); }
        }
    }
}
```

Called in the View thus:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Document>
@using CustomerDashboard.ViewModels;
@using CustomerDashboard.Utilities;
@{ Layout = null; }
    @foreach (Document doc in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@doc.DownloadLink" class="documentDownload">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 li-row li-row-icon">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img height="40" src="/Content/img/file-icons/@doc.Icon" />
                    </div>
                    ...
             </a>
        </li>
    }
```

Whilst this is rendered directly in another View the link generated is fine, however, I'm serializing the partial and returning as JSON:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        //https://gist.github.com/timiles/2828976 
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                     viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                         ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

It's then returned as Json from the controller:

```
        return Json(new { 
            totalCount = (int)Session["DocumentTotalCount"], 
            markup = RenderRazorViewToString("_DocumentListAjax", docs) 
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To be clear though, the problem is happening before the JSON serialization - this is nasty but removes the www prefix:

```
        return Json(new { 
            totalCount = (int)Session["DocumentTotalCount"], 
            markup = RenderRazorViewToString("_DocumentListAjax", docs).Replace("www.","") 
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

When doing this, from what appears to be from outside the LAN (which sounds odd), all the urls have www prepended - ie https://example.com becomes https://www.example.com. I'm struggling to track down why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: How is this resulting in JSON?

Comment: @MichałKędrzyński I've edited the question

Comment: what url are you using for the ajax call or how is the url for the ajax call generated?  Is it a full url or just a relative url?

Comment: @Kevin its relative and the correct link is called as per the comments in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

With your code, the described behavior can only occur when servicing different requests. Rendering of the partial view inside another view must happen as a result of handling an http request whose context's host is set to `example.com` (e.g a request to https://example.com/viewWithAPartialView).

Serving JSON containing a partial view, on the other hand is done as a result of handling a request to `www.example.com` (e.g. a request to https://www.example.com/getPartialViewJson/partialViewName).

Since rendering the partial view inside its master view is probably done 
when browsing the website via its "normal" url - everything goes as planned.

The JSON endpoint might be queried via AJAX, check the code that forms the request - it is the culprit. Another possibility is that you have URL rewriting set up to strip the `www` prefix, and for some reason the rewriting rule does not match the JSON serving endpoint.

**Update:**

Given the additional information it looks like the issue can be related to hosting configuration (IIS and load balancer settings). What I can suggest is to try to add the following line to your web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  ...
  <add key="aspnet:UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl" value="true" />
  ...
</appSettings>
```

This will force ASP.NET to use the host header from incoming requests
instead of asking for a server name variable. If the cause of the issue is indeed a configuration problem this should help.

Comment: You're quite correct that the partial view is indeed called via `AJAX`, however the link is relative and is correct - the url called doesn't have www prefixed. There are no re-write rules on either the internal staging server where things work, nor on the live environment

Comment: So, basically on one of the pages of `test.com`, you make a `$.ajax` request to `/getPartialViewJson/partialViewName`. At the time of this request, the url entered in the browser is `test.com/something` without the `www` prefix. Is that right? In other words, you see in a network explorer that an `ajax` request have just happened to `test.com` without `www`.

Comment: I have updated the answer to account for this. Check it out.

Comment: That got it, much appreciated

Comment: Whilst this appeared to work, it still does not, but it seems temperamental